# Adding others rw permission to file

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I have list of file with permission `-rw-r-----`. I want modify this permission and give access to other. i.e

`-rw-r--rw-`

Without modifying current permission setting, just add permission to 'other' user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
chmod o+rw yourfile
```

For **o**ther add (**+**) **r**ead and **w**rite permissions. I think it's quite semantically meaningful.

Alternatively, you could learn the numeric notation. R is worth 4, W is worth 2 and X is worth 1. If you want read *and* write, for example, you add 4 and 2 together giving 6.

So to keep the permissions the same for owner (6) and group (4) you could do:

```
chmod 646 yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

To add `rw` permissions use:

```
chmod o+rw <filemame>
```

---

To remove `w` for other:

```
chmod o-w <filename>
```

---

Likewise for group:

```
chmod g+rw <filename>
```

And for owner:

```
chmod u+rw <filename>
```